# Possibility to Extract more than one XML from Database

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, extract

I am currently trying to get more than one XML out of the Database. 
I do that for every XML spereatly I Need. I tried to add ID's with , etc.

```
SELECT extract(xmltype(uncompressed_host_xml), '/XXX) 
FROM XXXX 
WHERE id = XXXXXXXX;
```

I would like to add a bunch of ID's so that I can extract all of the XML's together and save them as seperate Documents.

Comment: Hi @SaschKO, what database do you use ? That would be very helpful information. Thanks!

Comment: @VBokšić i am working with Oracle MySQL

Comment: Hi @SaschKO I am sorry but there is no such thing. It is Oracle or MySQL. Or you need the solution for both. :) Check that and let us know.

Comment: @VBoka i would need it for Oracle DB :-) MySQL would be an additional Option.